# CSS positioning/resizing html5 video background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, resize

Hey all you wizards of the interwebs,
I've been pulling my hair out for the past couple of days trying to figure this one out.

I'm trying to include a fullscreen video background and it seems I have hit a snag.

Below is an image of what I am trying to accomplish.

I tried it with the video element as well as an iframe. I can't get the div below to always nest under, when the browser window is resized.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated. Closest I've gotten was with a min-width/height but it still leaves a gap...

What I end up with is what shws in the 2nd img. The video resizes with the browser and there's a gap below it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the problem you need to do this:

css:

```
.div1{ background-color: red; height: 100%; position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
.div2{ background-color: black; height: 100%;}
video{ position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; top: 0; bottom:0; right: 0; left: 0;}
```

and put your video inside div1:

```
<div class="div1">
     <video autoplay>...</video>
</div>
<div class="div2">
</div>
```

It don't allow video element to show at overflow. and div1 is always height:100% and div2 is always height:100%.

If you like to fit the video to the div1 add

```
 object-fit: cover;
```

to the video tag.

**IE Doesn't Support object-fit**

Comment: wow, that object-fit: cover does exactly what I wanted... how's x-browser support for it? also if you don't mind me asking how would I go about adding a width constraint on top of everything else? let's say If I resize the browser to a specific width the video is hidden and a placeholder img is shown instead as a bg img for that div

Comment: Object-fit doesn't fix your problem alone. You need to wrap video element and hide overflow. And as Always IE! IE doesn't support object-fit and It's under construction for Edge. see browser compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit  if you want to change elements style in each browser width or height just use "media". here you can see some examples: https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/ for your example if you want to change video and .div1 style on browser width 600 just write @media (max-width: 600px) { video { display: none; } .div1{ background-color: red;} }

Comment: got it... it works super. one more thing if I may... how would I add a poster img to div1 that would scale with the viewport? I need to display the first frame of the video but the jpeg is 1920x1080 and it won't scale with the window.

Comment: create div and Set your image as background-image and then background-size: cover; IE9+ Support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but 
Have you tried removing width: 100% and only keeping height: 100% ?

I might be able to give better suggestions, if you can show the code :p

EDIT:
Since you want height to be screen height and width can be more or less, I'd say, try

```
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
```

This should do the trick

NEW EDIT:

```
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.videoInsert {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
}
video{
      display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
      object-fit: fill;
}
```

Comment: `#wrapper {width: 100%; height: 100%;}`

Comment: `.videoInsert {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    min-height: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: -100;
}`

Comment: `<div class="wrapper">
  <video autoplay loop muted class="videoInsert">
  <source src="motion/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
</div>`

Comment: did you try using
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;

Comment: with this: .wrapper {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
.videoInsert { background-size: cover; height: 100%; left: 0; min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index: -100; } I get a decent resizing but the width obviously does not fill the viewport

Comment: Try whats written in the edit (above) 
inside .videoInsert

Comment: does not work. it adds a scroll bar to the width and makes the video taller than 100%

Comment: whats the aspect ratio of the video ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123990/discussion-between-cnapsys-and-visrozar).